# SQLContext not created : NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/rules/RuleExecutor

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I wish to load data from postgres to java spark. For this I am creating SQLContext but getting the following error:

[image]

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you confirm if you have spark-catalyst jar in your class path?

Comment: added the catalyst jar, now am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputCommitter error

Comment: Add parquet-hadoop jar to classpath. How are you managing dependencies in your application?

Comment: am using maven to manage dependencies, i have added parquet-hadoop, still am getting the same error.

Comment: my bad, i was adding com.twitter group-id for parquet-hadoop instead of org.apache. thanks anyways. pls answer this question so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following dependency to maven pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add 'spark-catalyst_2.10.jar' in build/class path to solve this issue.

Comment: added, now am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputCommitter error

Comment: Add this jar - parquet-hadoop-1.2.4.jar in build/class path. Check one all the supporting jars are added.